# I get the error: TypeError: items.map is not a function, when I try to add my API key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I use this component, I get the following error. When I used the exact same function only with another API it worked and I got the output from the API.

> TypeError: items.map is not a function
> ApiInfo.render
> C:/Users/32479/mikiesoftMovies2/cinemaReact-master/src/components/ApiInfo.js:35
>
> ```
> 32 | 
> 33 |     return (
> 34 |     <div className = "App">
> 35 |         <h1> Fetch data from an api in react </h1>  {
> | ^  36 |             items.map((item) => ( 
> 37 |             <ol key = { item.id } >
> 38 |                 Title: { item.original_title }
> ```

When I try it with another API it worked and I got no errors at all. I'm new to React so I don't know what's wrong.

This is my code (with the API that gives me the error) it's just a code that requests the info from the API and puts it in an `ol`:

```
import React from "react";

export class ApiInfo extends React.Component {
    
    // Constructor 
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
   
        this.state = {
            items: [],
            DataisLoaded: false
        };
    }
   
    // ComponentDidMount is used to
    // execute the code 
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(
"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=55957fcf3ba81b137f8fc01ac5a31fb5&language=en-US&page=1")
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((res) => {
                this.setState({
                    items: res,
                    DataisLoaded: true
                });
            })
    }
    render() {
        const { DataisLoaded, items } = this.state;
        if (!DataisLoaded) return <div>
            <h1> Please wait some time.... </h1> </div> ;
   
        return (
        <div className = "App">
            <h1> Fetch data from an api in react </h1>  {
                items.map((item) => ( 
                <ol key = { item.id } >
                    Title: { item.original_title }
                    </ol>
                ))
            }
        </div>
    );
}
}
   
   
export default ApiInfo;
```

and I will add an example of the json from the API I'm using:
[the json from the API unminified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaNpa.png)

Comment: `items: res` <- did you check what this actually assigned? _Is_ it an array?

Answer (score 1):

The movies items that you are looking for, are returned by The Movie Database API in `res.results`, not in `res`:

```
this.setState({
    items: res.results,
    DataisLoaded: true
});
```

**See the [API Reference for top-rated movies](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/get-top-rated-movies)**

*As a side note, it is a good practice to handle HTTP error cases, so consider adding a catch block to your fetch call.*

Comment: this worked. thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped. Consider marking the post as solved, so as to help the community.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `items` is not an array. Therefore `map` is not a function. Print out the variable `res` and you will see what is hidden behind and what you have to assign to `items`.